# Formula field is not working as expected

Tags: formula, tasks

I created a formula field to know the created task is for contact or opportunity or lead. So I tried to create a formula field Based on whatId & whoId.

But it throws a syntax error. Can anyone tell me where I have been going wrong

For reference:

```
IF(
BEGINS(WhatId, “006”), "Opportunity",

IF(
BEGINS(WhatId, “001”), “Account”,

IF(
BEGINS(WhoId, “00Q”), “Lead”,

IF(
BEGINS(WhoId, “003”), “Contact”,””))))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming your formula was copied directly from salesforce.com, the problem has to do with "Smart Quotes." Salesforce formulas don't recognize `“` and `”` as actual quotation marks. Try using the following:

```
IF(
BEGINS(WhatId, "006"), "Opportunity",

IF(
BEGINS(WhatId, "001"), "Account",

IF(
BEGINS(WhoId, "00Q"), "Lead",

IF(
BEGINS(WhoId, "003"), "Contact",""))))
```

Coincidentally, you could shorten your formula:

```
CASE(LEFT(WhatId, 3), "006", "Opportunity", "001", "Account",
CASE(LEFT(WhoId, 3), "00Q", "Lead", "003", "Contact", ""))
```

Comment: I am even confused why the OP needs a formula, when you hover over the related to field it does show you the actual sobject with minpage layout view.

Comment: @Rao Only in certain contexts, though. You can't do this in a report, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I think you're better off writing a `before trigger`. The obvious advantage of the below strategy is that it scales to all objects you can use for these polymorphic lookups. I did check that you can't use `What.Type` or `Who.Type` in a formula.

For the `Apex` approach, you just need to call (using the handler pattern of your choice):

```
public static void updateWhatType(List<Task> records)
{
    for (Task record : records) record.WhatType__c = getType(record.WhatId);
}
public static void updateWhoType(List<Task> records)
{
    for (Task record : records) record.WhoType__c = getType(record.WhoId);
}
public static String getType(Id value)
{
    return (value == null) ? null : String.valueOf(record.WhatId.getSObjectType());
}
```